# iframe force close the app in android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have used iframe to open the webpage in my android phonegap app.When the iframe is open and suddenly if the network connection fails then it showing the error as 'A secure connection could not be established(http://www.google.com).' and app force close.

Here is my code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.google.com");
$("#IframeDiv").append(iframe);
```

Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the google site coming on ur MOBILE device

Answer (score 0):

I cannot solve the sudden app exit but you can make the chances very low if you refer to `online variable (shown below)`, before opening the iframe.

```
  var online = false;

  var fnRegisterHandler = function(evtName, fn) {
    document.addEventListener(evtName, fn, false);
  };

  fnRegisterHandler("online", function(){ online = true; });
  fnRegisterHandler("offline", function() { online = false; });
```

Comment: Thanks raghaw...I need to check the net connection continuously.so that i can avoid force close after i open the iframe.How to do this.?

Comment: No just refer to variable 'online'. It will always have right value

Comment: Its working fine in android 2.2 but online and offline method repeatedly called in android 4.0.So i cant able to fix this problem in android 4.0

Comment: I have this code in production and have not felt any issue. I am working with API 10 and Android 2.3 & 4.0. Have not faced a single problem due to this. My Phonegap version is 2.0. If the online is being called repeatedly in the start, it may be OK behavior, let it settle down.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you need to Configure the PhoneGap.plist file of your app and add the domain that you're going to use in your iframe to the white List :

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES
ExternalHosts
     *.yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Thanks Imadt...Where to add this in my android phonegap app?

Comment: if you can't found the "PhoneGap.plist" look for "Cordova.plist"